# I wish not to add equal vectors together (or list in its absence)

Tags: java, list, set

I wish not to add equal vectors together (or list in its absence). When I add two equal numbers in a set, only one is added, but when I add two equal vectors, the two are added. Does anyone know how to solve it? My code:

```
    int[] a = new int[] {0,1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int[] b = new int[] {0,1,2,3,4,5,6};

     Set setExample = new HashSet();
     setExample.add(a);
     setExample.add(b);
```

The set "setExample" have a & b.

Comment: Arrays don't use value equality. You could use `List`s instead.

Comment: That's not a vector. It's an array. Don't use arrays. Use lists (or any other class containing your values and properly overriding equals() and hashCode()) . Arrays can only be equal to themselves. They don't override equals() and hashCode().

Comment: @khelwood but in the lists you can repeat elements, right?

Comment: Yes, just as in arrays.

Comment: I mean use lists instead of arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays don't use value equality, so a set won't see two similar arrays as duplicates. You could use lists instead. The standard implementations of `List` override `equals` and `hashCode` so that two lists with the same content are regarded as equal.

```
List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
List<Integer> b = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
Set<List<Integer>> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add(a);
set.add(b);
// set will only contain one list
```